# Observable is always undefined when transform the value using map

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm trying to understand why when I transform the observable it comes up undefined in the console log even though I know it has values assigned to it.

**Http Request**

```
getLibraryCardPeople(bookName: String): Observable<people[]> {
return this.http.get<LibraryCard>(url).pipe(map(results => results.people));
}
```

**JSON response**

```
book : "LOTR"
people : [
    {"name" : "joe", "age" : 20 , "Location": [...]},
    {"name" : "sarah", "age" : 16 , "Location": [...]}
]
```

When I execute the function and try and observe the people array is always undefined in the console log. However, If I don't map, I can see the entire JSON Response is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `subscribe` to the httpClient. First `subscribe` will activate the http call so to say.

```
getLibraryCardPeople(bookName: String): Observable<people[]> {
  return this.http.get<LibraryCard>(url);
}
```

Then in your component:

```
this.myService.getLibraryCardPeople.subscribe(data => {
  data.pipe(map(results => results.people));
})
```

This is the normal way to use `HttpClient`. What you can do, too, is to use `toPromise` from `RxJS`. Read all about [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise). A example:

```
this.http.get<LibraryCard>(url).toPromise()
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => { console.log ('error');
```

Comment: I thought you're supposed to use pipe and map for a nested object?

Comment: Yes. It's a typo. Sorry. pipe => map. But the way is the same: you need `subscribe`

Comment: Why can't it be transformed before it's subscribed first?

Comment: The httpClient gives first the data when subscribe is called. You can't transform data they not available. Then the httpClient (Observable) call its `next` command. And then subscribe gets data. To call http.get(....) will initialize the Observable, but "not" call its next/complete method. So you need to subscribe, or use toPromise.